# Form action incorrect when set with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form on a page with two inputs.  On submission, I would like the page redirected to a link that contains the values of the two inputs, plus a preceding string.  The html is the following:

```
<form name="searchForm">
    <label for="property_type">Property Type</label>
    <select name="property_type" id="property_type_number">
        <option value>- All Property Types -</option>
        <option value="1432">Commercial</option>
        <option value="1433">Land</option>
        <option value="1434">MultiFamily</option>
        <option value="1435">Rental</option>
        <option value="1436">Residential</option>
        <option value="1988">Residential / Condo</option>
        <option value="1987">Residential / Single Family</option>
    </select>

    <label for="city">City</label>
    <select name="city" id="city_number">
        <option value>- All Property Types -</option>
        <option value>--</option>
        <option value="cambridge">Cambridge</option>
        <option value="zanesville">Zanesville</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Search for Properties" onclick="searchform()">
</form>
```

And the Javascript is the following:

```
function searchform() 
{
    var propertyType = document.getElementById("property_type_number").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city_number").value;

    target = "/idx/?" + city + propertyType + "hi";

    document.searchForm.action = target;
}
```

When I submit the form, it seems to only use the first string of the target variable ("/idx/?") but ignore the rest.  It then inserts the values from the form automatically.  I would like it to go to a custom target such as the one above.

If you want to see it on the web, the address is:  http://lainegabriel.net/ (it is the last widget on the left).

Comment: Here worked on Chrome 26, picking Land / Zaneville gives `idx/?property_type=1433&city=zanesville`. What browser you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome 28; I also noticed that the "hi" string I inserted at the end for test purposes, wasn't included.  It appears to only take the first part ("/idx/?") for some reason.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why use a developer version prone to bugs?  Tested on 'current' chrome, firefox, IE9.. [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/WXNe5/).

Comment: But if you look closely, the target variable in my JS function does not match the url it is redirected to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't explain why the form behaves as such, or why it doesn't work, since it would appear that every bit of information online says to do exactly what you're doing..  I can however, provide a work-around:

Firstly, change your html to this, deleting the 'onclick' from the submit button, and replacing the form tag:

```
<form name="searchForm" onsubmit="return searchform();">
```

Secondly, in your `searchform()` function:

```
function searchform() {
    var propertyType = document.getElementById("property_type_number").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city_number").value;


    target = "/idx/?" + city + propertyType + "hi";

    document.searchForm.action = target; // I just left this in here just in case you wanted it.
    window.location.href = target; // redirect the window to the new url/action
    return false; // prevent the default submit action from occurring
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/WXNe5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
var propertyType = document.getElementById("property_type_number").value;
var city = document.getElementById("city_number").value;
```

with this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("property_type_number");
var propertyType = select.options[ select.selectedIndex ].value;
select = document.getElementById("city_number");
var city= select.options[ select.selectedIndex ].value;
```

Any difference?

i know its bigger in code but i never had problems with that (before i switched to *jquery* and forget all these kind of problems..)